# Why does my logic below in the assign() method not work: instead of node[0] and node[1] I used node.value[0] and node.value[1]?

Tags: python, oop, linked-list

```
from linked_list import Node, LinkedList
from blossom_lib import flower_definitions

class HashMap():
  def __init__(self, size):
    self.array_size = size
    self.array = [LinkedList() for number in range(size)]

  def hash(self, key):
    return sum(key.encode())

  def compress(self, hash_code):
     return hash_code % self.array_size

  def assign(self, key, value):
    array_index=self.compress(self.hash(key))
    payload = Node([key, value])
    #self.array[array_index] = [key, value]
    list_at_array = self.array[array_index]
    for node in list_at_array:
      if node.value[0] == key: #as node has the above definition of payload = Node([key, value]) it basically says we have a node with value = [key, value]
        node.value[1] = value
    list_at_array.insert(payload)

  def retrieve(self, key):
    array_index = self.compress(self.hash(key)) 
    list_at_index = self.array[array_index]
    for node in list_at_index:
      if node.value[0] == key:
        return node.value[1]
      else:
        return None  
    if payload[0] == key:
      return payload[1]
    elif payload[0] == None or payload[0]  !=key:
      return None


blossom = HashMap(len(flower_definitions))
for flower in flower_definitions:
  blossom.assign(flower[0],flower[1])
print(flower_definitions)
```

Output:

> Error: LinkedList does not have a value attribute.

`LinkedList` is a linked list class that stores different nodes of the Node class i.e. `Node(value)`

By the node definition, we have the following constructor:

```
self.value = value
```

...and the `value` is the key-value pair i.e. `[key,value]`.

However, it tells me that the item within the linked list (in my opinion item = instances of Node class) does not have a value attribute.

My logic:

```
list_at_array = self.array[array_index]
```

...where `array_index` marks the position in the array where we add the key-value pair. The array is a number of LinkedLists - whose items are nodes - with the size of all the flowers that are stored within `flower_definitions`. Hence, `list_at_array` selects the first entry of the selected `LinkedList` object - by definition a node.

If we now we just decide that we add a key-value pair to the `LinkedList` called `list_at_array` then we basically tell the `LinkedList` object to behave like a normal list?

Comment: Please provide the code for `Node` and `LinkedList` and the content of `flower_definitions` for which you get the error. NB: you have an invalid reference in `retrieve`: `payload` is referenced but not defined. Also, the `for` loop in that method will never do more than one iteration, when it will `return`.